# How to sync a FeatureTable with a FeatureLayer's selection set?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, attribute-table, feature-layer

The ArcGIS Server JS API contains a new [FeatureTable](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featuretable-amd.html) class, which shows the attribute table corresponding to a FeatureLayer. There is an option [syncSelection](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featuretable-amd.html#syncselection) which:

> Enables an interaction between the map and the feature table. Setting
>   this property to true allows selection of a feature on a map via
>   clicking row in the table, and selection of a table's row via clicking
>   a feature on the map

However, this doesn't seem to honour a selection set made **programatically** against the layer.

Taking the sample at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=featuretable, if I apply a selection to the FeatureLayer it is not reflected in the FeatureTable:

```
// Create the feature layer
myFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Warren_College_Trees/FeatureServer/0", {
  mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,
  visible: true,
  outFields: ["*"],
  id: "fLayer"
});
var myQuery = new Query();
myQuery.where = "Spp_Code ='SABA'";
myFeatureLayer.selectFeatures(myQuery,FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW)
```

This correctly applies the selection to the feature layer (note that the map only contains one point), but not to the feature table (it lists all 1146 points with 0 selected):

[image]

Is there a way to refresh the feature table to reflect the selection set?

Comment: As a note, I tried to call myFeatureTable.grid.select() on rows where the FID matched the selection results in the featureLayer "selection-complete" callback, and I ran into circular callbacks. Perhaps adding a check to see if the row was selected or not would have worked. Will research more later.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution for viewing only what it is visible on the map (in view:)

```
    _selectViewIds: function() {
        var objectIdFieldName = this.layer.layerObject.objectIdField;
        q = new Query();
        q.outFields = [objectIdFieldName];
        q.geometry = this.map.extent;
        var exp=this.layer.layerObject.getDefinitionExpression();
        q.where = exp;
        q.returnGeometry = true;
        new QueryTask(this.layer.layerObject.url).execute(q).then(lang.hitch(this, function(ev) {
            var selectedIds = ev.features.map(function(f) {return f.attributes[objectIdFieldName];});

            this.myFeatureTable.filterRecordsByIds(selectedIds);
        }));
    }
```

...

```
        on(selectFeaturesBtn, 'change', lang.hitch(this, function(ev) {
            if(selectFeaturesBtn.isChecked()) {
                this._selectViewIds();
                on(this.map, "extent-change", lang.hitch(this, this._selectViewIds, this));
            } else {
                this.myFeatureTable.clearFilter();
            }
        }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Beginning at 3.16 and later, the implementation of that `SyncSelection` boolean is slightly different than you described:

> Enables an interaction between the map and the feature table. Setting
>   this property to true allows selection of a feature on a map via
>   clicking a row in the table. **However, it won't enable selection of
>   records in the table when user clicks on a feature on the map.** To
>   enable selection from the map to the table, **the developer must
>   explicitly implement the layer's click logic.** This is because the
>   application might have its own selection logic elsewhere or their own
>   click logic. (Added at v3.16)

So, I know it's a royal pain, but I believe you have to loop through the map-layers selected features and select them AGAIN by call the selection click event on them (programmatically.)

Answer (score 2):

Hook to the `selection-complete` event, use `getSelectedFeatures()`, map the result to an array of IDs, and pass that to the `FeatureTable` via `selectRows`. Then hook `selectFeatures` to the `click` event and you're done.

As a rough idea:

```
layer.on("click", function(evt) {
    var query = new Query();
    query.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
    layer.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function() {
        var ids = layer.getSelectedFeatures().map(function(feature) {
            return feature.attributes[objectIDFieldName];
        });
        featureTable.selectRows(ids);
    });
}
```